# React Native stuck on Loading dependency graph, done and when go to localhost:8081, I see React Native packager is running

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

**Env**:
Mac OS X
nodejs 8.9.1
Xcode installed
using boilerplate generated by https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app

**Symptom**:
React Native stuck on Loading dependency graph, done and when go to localhost:8081, I see React Native packager is running.

[image]

Also the command line after I did `npm start` what I got is `Loading dependency graph, done.` and just stay there, even after I waited for almost 5min.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I found the answer myself.

There is actually nothing wrong. I forgot to start the React Native in the simulator! lol Silly right?

So basically let say if you want to start the iOS simulator in a MacOS, you can just do `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 5s"` in your project root. Then boom! your project started!

Note that React Native can't really run in the browser, it has to be running inside a phone simulator either iOS or Android.

See official doc for more https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-simulator-ios.html

Have fun!

Comment: Doesn't work with me. It doesn't even open the simulator.

Comment: @TomSawyer check if you have any console error as well as if you have installed all the dependencies required for react native. hope it helps a bit!

Comment: i also use npm start and the problem persists.. how to start the simulator through npm start?

Comment: I can start the simulator with expo start, rn start, react native run ios etc. but what is the use of npm start then when it doesnt starts the emulator?